# Two Questions Involving Differential Equations Calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the equation $x''(t)+k^2x(t)=0$, how do I find a correct solution to the equation? I tried letting $x(t) = c$, where c is a constant, so that $x'(t) = 0$. But the equation won't make sense since $x''(t)$ will also be 0, and there won't be a solution. I consulted with someone else and they said that it should be a sinusoidal equation - which I don't know how to obtain from this.

Comment: These should really be asked as two separate questions.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post to only have 1 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just answer the first question for now. Your friend said it should be a sinusoid because the equation relates the derivative of a function to the function itself - think of how the second derivative of sine is a constant times sine itself.

More generally, it would be better to use an exponential (because by Euler's formula sines and cosines are linear combinations of exponentials). So assume your function has form $x(t)=ce^{lt}$ for some undetermined $c,l$. Substitute this into your equation to get $cl^2e^{lt}+k^2ce^{lt}=0$. You can cancel the exponentials here and just get an algebraic equation for $l$ in terms of $k$. So $l = \pm ik$. Since linear combinations of solutions to homogenous ODEs are also solutions, we have to add the solution with $l=ik$ and the solution with $l=-ik$. Our solution said nothing about $c$, in order to get this kind of information you would need some initial conditions. Hence your solution is $x(t) = c_1e^{ikt}+c_2e^{-ikt}$.

Comment: Note you can use Euler's formula to get your solution in terms of sines and cosines. Try this solution for yourself so it makes sense to you.